# groovy error MissingPropertyException: No such property

Tags: java, groovy

I am doing a groovy tutorial and I used the code from the book 'Programming Groovy'.
I used the following code in the book to learn about event handlers in Groovy:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.event.*
import java.awt.Container.*
import java.lang.*

frame = new JFrame(size: [300, 300],
    layout: new FlowLayout(),
    defaultCloseOperation: java.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
button = new JButton("click")
positionLabel = new JLabel("")
msgLabel = new JLabel("")
frame.contentPane.add button
frame.contentPane.add positionLabel
frame.contentPane.add msgLabel

button.addActionListener({ JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You clicked!")} as ActionListener)

displayMouseLocation = {positionLabel.setText("$it.x, $it.y")}
frame.addMouseListener(displayMouseLocation as MouseListener)
frame.addMouseMotionListener(displayMouseLocation as MouseMotionListener)

handle = [
    focusGained : {msg.Label.setText("Good to see you!") },
    focusLost : {msg.Label.setText("Come back soon!") }
]
button.addFocusListener(handleFocus as FocusListener)

events = ['WindowListener', 'ComponentListener']

handler = {msg.Label.setText("$it") }

for (event in events)
{
    handleImpl = handler.asType(Class.forName("java.awt.event.${event}"))
    frame."add${event}"(handlerImpl)
}

frame.show()
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I am getting an error on line 8 that says:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: java for class: execise2
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at execise2.run(execise2.groovy:8)

What am I missing?  I feel that it is something simple, but I can't find it.

thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package on `java.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is wrong.  It should be `javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.  The error message is confusing because groovy is trying to interpret `java.swing...` as the field `swing` on a variable named `java`.

Also, since you're importing `javax.swing` already, just use `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 2):

For `WindowConstants`, you can replace:

```
java.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```

with

```
javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```

or simply

```
WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```